# Updating all table Records with with its corresponding data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

the thing is, i have a table students table and another scores table and i already have all the students in the scores table but the class field is still empty so, i thought i could update all of them with the data from the the students table. each students with his/her class.

```sql
UPDATE scores_tbl
    INNER JOIN students_tbl
        ON scores_tbl.reg_id = students_tbl.reg_id
    SET scores_tbl.class = IF(students_tbl.class > 0, students_tbl.class, scores_tbl.class) 
WHERE scores_tbl.session ="2018/2019";
```

am displayed with: **Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value**

Comment: Table definitions and sample data would be nice.

Comment: ```"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"``` means you're trying to compare a number and a string in a WHERE or ON clause. What are the datatypes of ```students_tbl.class```, ```scores_tbl.reg_id``` and ```students_tbl.reg_id```?

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau the datatypes are varchar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE scores_tbl
    INNER JOIN students_tbl
        ON scores_tbl.reg_id = students_tbl.reg_id
    SET scores_tbl.class = IF(IFNULL(students_tbl.class, 0) > 0, IFNULL(students_tbl.class, 0), IFNULL(scores_tbl.class, 0)) 
WHERE scores_tbl.session ="2018/2019";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Since you only want to update the record if `student_tbl.class` has any value. It is better to write this condition in where clause and simplify your query.

```
UPDATE scores_tbl
    INNER JOIN students_tbl
        ON scores_tbl.reg_id = students_tbl.reg_id
    SET scores_tbl.class = students_tbl.class 
WHERE scores_tbl.session ="2018/2019" and cast(students_tbl.class as int) > 0;
```

I am expecting that class column has only integer values.